# How can I access the ANTLR parse tree?

Tags: java, antlr4, antlrworks2

I am using ANTLR v. 4.5.2, ANTLRWorks 2.1 and the made available [grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/tsql) for tSQL right now.

ANTLRWorks generates me a perfect parse tree from my SQL code but I want to use ANTLR in my webapplication (without ANTLRWorks).

I already generated my `tsql.tokens`, `BaseListener`, `lexer`, and so on but **how** can I call ANTLR from an already existing Java class?

I don't need the parse tree as graphic I need just Java objects for the parse tree nodes (for example SET_STATEMENTS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once generated from .g4 files, those Java source files can be include in your Java project and compiled together with your other files.

You don't need those .g4 files to be compiled at runtime.

Comment: ok but I have one more question: can you tell me which methods I need to call and to overhand my String (my SQL code) --> or a refer link, thanks

Comment: @NappyBoy there are tons of examples on Google, http://www.theendian.com/blog/antlr-4-lexer-parser-and-listener-with-example-grammar/ so search for them and learn from them.